# pandas groupby agg count when condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

Is there any way to aggregate data after group with non-condition and condition?

```
df.groupby(["GRP_1", "GRP_2", "GRP_3"], as_index=False).agg(P_cnt = (num_str, 'count'),
                                                            C_cnts = (C_cnt, 'sum'),
                                                            C_cnts_positive = (C_cnt>=0, 'sum'))
df.dtypes
GRP_1     object
GRP_2     object
GRP_3     object
num_str   object
C_cnt     float64
```

Comment: you could try writing a lambda function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you would need to create a new column for `C_cnt>=0`. For example:

```
(df.assign(pos_C_cnts=df['C_cnt'].clip(0))
   .groupby(["GRP_1", "GRP_2", "GRP_3"], as_index=False)
   .agg(P_cnt=('num_str', 'count'),             # column name need be strings
        C_cnts=('C_cnt', 'sum'),                # 'sum' not 'Sum'
        C_cnts_positive=('pos_C_cnts', 'sum'))
)
```

or use a `lambda`  function (which would be a bit slower)

```
(df.groupby(["GRP_1", "GRP_2", "GRP_3"], as_index=False)
   .agg(P_cnt=('num_str', 'count'),
        C_cnts=('C_cnt', 'sum'),
        C_cnts_positive=('C_cnt', lambda x: x.clip(0).sum())
)
```